# Can htaccess prevent all access to unwanted files?

Tags: .htaccess, security

I'm building something that I want to release as an open source project. To make it easier to use I'd like to go without the public-folder approach, where you hide all other files than `index.php` (and assets) from `public_html`. Meaning, I'd like to do it like WordPress, where you simply toss the code on a server and it works, in that URL you tossed it in.

Here is the content of my htaccess-file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Does this code really prevent access to other files? For example, is there any way an attacker could access `vendor/Acme/Libraries/Foo.php`? Based on my tests it does, but that doesn't mean there isn't a way to circumvent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at your rule closely:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Here this rule is saying that if request is NOT for a valid file then rewrite it to `/index.php`. Which means `/index.php` will be invoked for any non-file requests but that also means you are **allowing** direct access to all the files.

btw **QSA is useless here** and can be removed.

You cited `Wordpress` here. Which basically uses `/index.php` for any non-file, non-directory requests thus *allowing direct access to any valid file OR directory*.

If you really want to block access to all the files and directories then you probably will need this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

but I am not sure if you want to handle direct access to resources like images, js/css files via `index.php` also.

Comment: Great reply. About assets: I can add a rule like this, no? Taken from another answer of yours: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets(/.*|)$ [NC]`

Comment: Yes definitely that `RewriteCond` will be handy in your case.

Comment: Okay. One more thing: why do you say QSA is useless? Let's say user requests `pretty/url?search=foo`, I will need the query string in that case.

Comment: Query string will be passed to you **as is**. `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one. That is useful only when you're adding a new query parameter in your rule.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an attacker can still access your other code files, using only the rule you provided.  But:

1. On a properly configured server, a call to `vendor/Acme/Libraries/Foo.php` would execute that file, not display its contents.  Which might or might not be good enough, and there's still the possibility of a configuration error that would display the source code.
2. You can block web access to the remaining files by adding `Deny` directives, for example:

   ```
   <Location />
     Order deny,allow
     Deny from all
     <Files index.php>
       Allow from all
     </Files>
   </Location>
   ```